# Task.Delay(-1) and GetAwaiter() in Discord bot

Tags: c#, discord.net

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
    new Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

private DiscordSocketClient _client;


public async Task MainAsync()
{
    _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
    _client.Log += Log;
    _client.MessageReceived += _client_MessageReceived;

    var token = File.ReadAllText("token.txt");

    await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
    await _client.StartAsync();

    await Task.Delay(-1);
}
```

Hello guys, just wanna say that im new to programming so i hope who read this post please go easy on me. So i've been trying to make a Discord bot and i got confused at the `new Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();` i've tried to google every parts of the statement and here's what i got, so the youtuber i watched wants to call the non-static MainAsync in the static Main() and the GetAwaiter().GetResult() will wait for the MainAsync method to be completed.

But i don't really understand the await Task.Delay(-1) and the GetAwaiter(), hope someone can tell me why he uses GetResult() with await Task.Delay(-1) and what's GetAwaiter(), thanks.

Comment: If you are new to programming then asynchronous programming is waaaay too advanced concept to start with. I'd start with the basics first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Task.Delay(-1)` blocks the process from exiting

`Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is equivalent to `await` task and is used when the method cannot be marked with `async`, in this case, the `Main` method. this is not recommended [read here for more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main)

Comment: Very easy to understand, i hope i can upvote your answer but i can't because my account is also new, sorry.